# Managed Metadata column is not supporting page content type

Tags: page-layout, managed-metadata, publishing-site

I have a SharePoint 2010 publishing site which is migrated from SharePoint 2007. When I try to add a managed metadata column to `Page` content type I am getting below alert

> The site column ‘managed_metadata’ might not be supported by earlier versions of client programs. Adding this column might block those programs from saving documents to this library. Are you sure you want to use this site column?

Even though the above alert pops up, I am able to add the column to the page content type.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

The browser I am using is Internet Explorer 11

Comment: I have the same issue when I migrate from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint Online. The error/warning is: Earlier versions of client programs might not support this type of column. Adding this column might block those programs from saving documents to this library.
if you have any idea please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to fix here. It's just a warning for power users / admins.

There really are some limitations when files from document libraries with managed metadata fields are opened in Office 2007. [Read this post at nothingbutsharepoint.com](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/12/21/managed-metadata-columns-in-office-2007-aspx-2/)

Answer (score 2):

As you migrated from 2007, there are files which are based on the 2007, so thats why you are getting this. `There is limited issues and it only associated to files with Microsoft office 2007 version.`

If you are using 2010 files then fine other wise may cause the issue. check the blog to catch the real issue "[Utilize the Managed Metadata Service application tip](http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2011/09/utilize-managed-metadata-service_20.html) "